# result of selection formula must be boolean crystal reports C# vs 2010

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
if {?Sort} LIKE "asc" then 
  crAscendingOrder
else
  crDescendingOrder
```

so this is my formula in formula workshop in crystal reports but when I save it there is an error it says: the result of selection formula must be boolean.

There is a dropdownbox in my design in which you can choose to sort the data in asc or desc order so the item that you will choose will go to {?Sort} so if you choose "asc" the data in crystal report should sort the last name in asc order when you click the button.

how can i solve it?

Comment: where are you placing this formula?

Comment: in my SortDecs formula

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't write this code in record selection formula or formula field, Instead you should write in sort control.

If you have created a group then go to change group and there you can see the option `Use formula as a group sort order` and there write this formula, Else you can check options in `record sort expert` and `group sort expert`